# PHP using XPath not returning value

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm trying to use XPath with PHP and I can't get it to simply return a value. Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

The result I get is:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )
```

but W3Schools says the result is supposed to be:

```
Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
  (
  [0] => Jani
  )
)
```

Here's what I'm using:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $XMLfile = "test.xml";

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($XMLfile);
    $result = $xml->xpath("from");
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: How about simply `echo $xml->from`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody is getting it.  But I know what you are missing  JaceG.

You are expecting print_r to show you 'Jani', but neither var_dump or print_r will show you 'Jani'.

Please add this after your print_r to test.

```
foreach ($result as $le_result)
      echo $le_result;
```

And there will be 'Jani'.

Neither var_dump or print_r, display useful output on DOM Objects. You have to look at them yourself.

Comment: Just to elaborate on why OP's expression works (since I found it surprising): `simplexml_load_file($XMLfile)` returns a reference to the root element, not the document itself.